# nodal lines in the dirichlet problem

Tags: eigenvalues, ap.analysis-of-pdes

In the Dirichlet problem if nodal lines do not touch $\partial\Omega$ (unit disk), what happens to the eigenvalues?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why do you need to know? Please have a read of http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask

Comment: If you are assuming $\Omega$ is a disk then the eigenvalues and eigenmodes can be computed explicitly. If I remember correctly, if the nodal lines do not touch the boundary of $\Omega$ then the eigenvalues are simple. (this is just for the disk)